# Loading data from API into vue.js using chart.js

Tags: javascript, api, vue.js, chart.js, vue-component

I am relatively new to Vuejs and API calling and I wanna find out how to fetch data from my API to display chart.

Currently, my code is:

```js
<script>
import axios from 'axios'

export default {
  name: 'Chart',

  props: ['data'],

  data: () => ({

  }),
  async mounted () {

    let result = await axios.get('http://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod?access_key=b2508f27f2cef3694a66d6adf4646f87&symbols=AAPL')
    this.data = result.data.data

    // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
    const data = ????? #need help here
    }))

    const ctx = document.getElementById('mychart').getContext('2d')
    // eslint-disable-next-line no-undef,no-unused-vars
    const Chart_2 = new Chart(ctx, {
      type: 'line',
      data: {
        datasets: [
          {
            data,
            label: 'Chart from API ',
            borderColor: '#7367F0'
          }
        ]
      },
      options: {
        scales: {
          xAxes: [
            {
            }
          ],
          yAxes: [
            {
            }
          ]
        }
      }
    })
  }
}
```

The above code is in a component Chart2.vue and will be displayed in App.vue. Would appreciate any help given!

The API URL: http://api.marketstack.com/v1/eod?access_key=b2508f27f2cef3694a66d6adf4646f87&symbols=AAPL

Comment: In data: () => ({ datafordatasets }), ... and in data: {
        datasets: [
          {
            data : this.datafordatasets,
            label: 'Chart from API ',
            borderColor: '#7367F0'
          }
        ]
      }, .... not sure how data in chartsjs have to look like.

Comment: Data in ChartJS should be an array of objects, like `[{x: '2019', y: 1}, {x: '2020', y: 2}]` - so you will want to format the response from the api into something like the above, and pass that in as data

Comment: and props coming from the parent, so i don't understand why you calling an api inside a component, which should get data from a parent.  So data must be inside of data not inside of props.

Comment: you'll need to define the mappped data from api in data function and bind that data variable to the chart component in the template